# PostgreSQL approaching plan caching on identical queries?

Tags: postgresql, caching, benchmarking

I am running some benchmarks tests on a lot of queries. I have a set of queries and they will be run multiple times after each other. I know that PostgreSQL caches query plans so this is important to consider but as far as I know this does not always happen.

So I have two approaches. I am considering to either (a) force the query plan to be generated each time I run a query or either (b) to 'warm up' a bit so that a plan is cached and it is reused each time. How can I perform either or what precautions can I take to ensure that one or the other is happening?

It would be great if I could monitor plans in the cache but I am not sure if it is possible.

UPDATE: My queries are complex SELECTs to retrieve data, no DELETEs/INSERTs etc. Does this mean I should not give so much respect to the query planner in benchmarks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL only caches query plans if

- you use prepared statements
- the statement is executed inside a [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) function

So if you want to benchmark how much faster your queries become if you avoid the overhead of planning, you should create a prepared statement and execute it al least six times (because the first five runs will always generate a custom plan).

If your queries are complex, odds are that you might even lose if you cache query plans, particularly if the runtime of the queries is long. In such a case, it is usually better to spend more effort on planning each query. The biggest win with prepared statements is when the execution time of the queries is low.

Comment: Thanks! You suggest benchmarking without overhead of planning through prepared statements. You also say PostgreSQL also caches query plans through PL/pgSQL functions - so is it implied that I can expect the same behaviour i.e. if I use a PL/pgSQL procedure and execute it at least 5 times, then I can safely expect cached plans on the 6th run onwards?

Comment: Yes, you got it right - in most of the cases. Sometimes PostgreSQL will decide that the generic plan is not good enough and continue generating custom plans. To test, you can use `EXPLAIN EXECUTE prepared_statement` or auto_explain for statements inside functions. If you see `$1` in there, a generic plan is used. Statements without parameters will of course always use the generic plan.

Comment: Thanks for your well-explained replies! Very helpful.

Comment: Hi @laurenz-albe,  what if I have a batch of queries Q1, ..., Qn in order. If I run this batch 6 times, can I expect the batch on the 6th turn to have a cached plan on all/some query or not?

Comment: Yes, unless (as explained in the comment above) the planner decides to stick with custom plans for a certain query.